# Kernel Bug : unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffff81e00520

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, kernel-panic

I am trying to replace system call __NR_rmdir in Kernel version 4.15.0-74-generic in Ubuntu 16.04 64bit but it gives following error.  The following code is working fine with Linux kernel version 2.6.35-22-generic in Ubuntu 10.10 64bit I have added source code after error:

```
[  133.631561] syscall_replace: sys_call_table address is 0x0000000030c42fec
[  133.631577] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffff81e00520
[  133.631582] IP: syscall_replace_init+0x1c/0x60 [syscall_replace]
[  133.631583] PGD 17700e067 P4D 17700e067 PUD 17700f063 PMD 0 
[  133.631587] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
[  133.631588] Modules linked in: syscall_replace(OE+) pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) input_leds ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 snd_rawmidi ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 aesni_intel aes_x86_64 xt_comment crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate nf_log_ipv4 binfmt_misc intel_rapl_perf snd_seq nf_log_common xt_LOG snd_seq_device i2c_i801 snd_timer xt_multiport wmi_bmof snd xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype mei_me lpc_ich shpchp soundcore mei ie31200_edac
[  133.631610]  mac_hid nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack libcrc32c iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 mii drm ahci libahci wmi video
[  133.631638] CPU: 3 PID: 2558 Comm: insmod Tainted: G        W  OE    4.15.0-74-generic #83~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[  133.631639] Hardware name: LENOVO 3492H2Q/, BIOS F1KT52AUS 05/24/2013
[  133.631641] RIP: 0010:syscall_replace_init+0x1c/0x60 [syscall_replace]
[  133.631642] RSP: 0018:ffffbbb7c275fc68 EFLAGS: 00010286
[  133.631643] RAX: 000000000000003d RBX: ffffffffc07e3040 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  133.631644] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff9f3d1f396498 RDI: ffff9f3d1f396498
[  133.631645] RBP: ffffbbb7c275fc68 R08: 0000000000010830 R09: ffffffff90b5c4c4
[  133.631646] R10: ffffbbb7c275fcb8 R11: 000000000000033c R12: ffffffffc07e10b0
[  133.631647] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000000001
[  133.631648] FS:  00007f6c1cfa2700(0000) GS:ffff9f3d1f380000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  133.631649] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  133.631650] CR2: ffffffff81e00520 CR3: 00000001d65ea006 CR4: 00000000001606e0
[  133.631651] Call Trace:
[  133.631657]  do_one_initcall+0x55/0x1ac
[  133.631662]  ? __vunmap+0x8e/0xc0
[  133.631664]  ? _cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[  133.631667]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xa6/0x1d0
[  133.631670]  do_init_module+0x5f/0x223
[  133.631672]  load_module+0x188c/0x1e90
[  133.631676]  ? ima_post_read_file+0x83/0xa0
[  133.631678]  SYSC_finit_module+0xe5/0x120
[  133.631680]  ? SYSC_finit_module+0xe5/0x120
[  133.631682]  SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
[  133.631684]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
[  133.631687]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
[  133.631688] RIP: 0033:0x7f6c1cad54d9
[  133.631689] RSP: 002b:00007ffe2b150f08 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[  133.631691] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055c5da68b270 RCX: 00007f6c1cad54d9
[  133.631691] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000055c5d9f4e26b RDI: 0000000000000003
[  133.631692] RBP: 000055c5d9f4e26b R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f6c1cd9aea0
[  133.631693] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000000
[  133.631694] R13: 000055c5da68b210 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[  133.631695] Code: ab ce 0f 1f 00 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 c7 c6 80 02 e0 81 48 c7 c7 60 20 7e c0 48 89 e5 e8 14 30 b1 ce <48> 8b 34 25 20 05 e0 81 48 c7 c7 98 20 7e c0 48 89 35 9e 22 00 
[  133.631715] RIP: syscall_replace_init+0x1c/0x60 [syscall_replace] RSP: ffffbbb7c275fc68
[  133.631716] CR2: ffffffff81e00520
[  133.631717] ---[ end trace fadfaa1785a9e6d9 ]---
```

source code :

```
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/utsname.h>
#include <asm/pgtable.h>

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("system call replace test module");
MODULE_AUTHOR("knqyf263");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


static void **syscall_table = (void *)0xffffffff81e00280;
typedef void (*sys_call_ptr_t)(void);


typedef asmlinkage int (*original_rmdir)(const char __user * pathname);



original_rmdir orig_rmdir = NULL;



asmlinkage long hooked_rmdir(const char __user * pathname) {

    pr_info("Cannot delete files and folder");
    return 0;
}

static void save_original_syscall_address(void){
    orig_rmdir = (original_rmdir) syscall_table[__NR_rmdir];
}

static void change_page_attr_to_rw(pte_t *pte){
    set_pte_atomic(pte, pte_mkwrite(*pte));
}

static void change_page_attr_to_ro(pte_t *pte){
    set_pte_atomic(pte, pte_clear_flags(*pte, _PAGE_RW));
}

static void replace_system_call(void *new){
    unsigned int level = 0;
    pte_t *pte;

    pte = lookup_address((unsigned long) syscall_table, &level);


    syscall_table[__NR_rmdir] = new;


    change_page_attr_to_ro(pte);
}

static int syscall_replace_init(void){
    pr_info("sys_call_table address is 0x%p\n", syscall_table);

    save_original_syscall_address();
    pr_info("original sys_uname's address is %p\n", orig_rmdir);

    replace_system_call(hooked_rmdir);

    pr_info("system call replaced\n");
    return 0;
}

static void syscall_replace_cleanup(void){
    pr_info("cleanup");
    if (orig_rmdir)
        replace_system_call(orig_rmdir);
}

module_init(syscall_replace_init);
module_exit(syscall_replace_cleanup);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems your error is about the address of you syscall table, due to the second line

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffff81e00520
```

the cause is probably the **KASLR** which introduced in the linux mainline at version 3.14.

**KASLR** stands for Kernel Address space layout randomization, which means the address at kernel will be randomized every time you boot the system, include the syscall table address, thus to get the correct address of it you should use one of the technique to acquire it such as search in the memory or using kallsysms_lookup_name.
for much more detailed teqchined you can read [here](https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/linux-kernel-module-rootkit-syscall-table-hijacking-8f1bc0bd099c)